# Heroku Request Timeout (H12) with Big Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Ruby on Rails application which gets lots of data from social media sites like Twitter, Facebook etc.

There is an index page that shows records as paged. I am using Kaminari for paging.

My issue is big data, I guess. Let's say I have millions of records and want to show them on my index page with Kaminari. When I tried to run the system by browser, Heroku gives me H12 error (request timeout).

What can I do to improve my app's performance? I have this idea of getting only the records that will be shown on the index page. Likewise, when clicked to Kaminari second page link, only fetching the second page records from database. Idea is basically that but I don't know where to start and how to implement it.

Here an example piece of code from my controller:

```
@ca_responses = @ca_responses_for_adaptors.where(:ca_request_id => @conditions)
                                                 .order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
                                                 .page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

@ca_responses: My records

@ca_responses_for_adaptor: Records based on adaptor. Think as admin and this returns all of the records.

@conditions: Getting specified adaptor records. For example getting only Twitter related records etc.

Comment: Can you show your controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by creating a page cache table which will be filled in with your data for your search results. That could be one approach. 
There could be few downsides, but if I would know the exact problem, then I could propose better solution. I doubt that you will be listing million users on one page and then to access them by paginating the pages (?) or I am mistaken

EDIT:

There could be few problems with pagination. First is that the paginating gems work like this: They fetch all data, and then when you click on page number it only fetches the second 5 elements (or however you have set it) from the whole list. The problem here is `fetching all the data before paginating`. If you have a million of records, then this could take a while for every page. You could define new method that will run SQL query to select one amount of data from the database , and you can set `offset` instruction to fetch the data only for that page. In this case paginate gem is useless, so you would need to remove it.

The second option is that you could use something like user_cashe, something like that. By this I mean to create new table that will have just a few records - the records that will be displayed on the screen. The table will be smaller then the usuall user table, and then, it would be faster to search trough it.

There could be other more advanced solutions, but I doubt you could (want) to use it in your application.

Comment: The above code is pretty same with this for admin user:
@ca_responses = CaResponse.page(params[:page]).per(5)
Is my problem trying to get all records at once?

Answer (score 0):

Kaminari already paginates your records as expected.

Heroku is prone to random timeout errors due to its [random router](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/4/3/routing_and_web_performance_on_heroku_a_faq).

Try to reproduce on local. You may have bottlenecks in your code which make indeed your request being too long to return. You should not have any problem requesting 5 items from database, so you may have code before or after that that takes long time to run.

If everything is ok on local with production data, you may add new_relic to analyze your requests and see whether some problem occurs specifically on production (and why).

If it appears heroku router is indeed the problem, you can still try to use unicorn as a webserver, but you have to take special care that your app does not consume too much memory (each unicorn worker will consume the ram of a whole app, and you may hit heroku memory limits, which would produce R14 errors in place of those H12).

Comment: you have a good point. I've tried these on local, too and there was no problem. So, I better add new_relic and analyze requests. But I'm not sure about Unicorn because I think my app can be a memory monster time to time.

Comment: Also, about local run : please note [heroku's timeout is 30 seconds](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout). I'm not sure thin and webrick have such enforced limit time. Are your requests on local under those 30 secs ?

Comment: I'm using thin and you're right, there isn't. But my local requests are mostly under 30 seconds. I'm not sure if I should switch to Unicorn.

Comment: Also, do you use heroku free plan ? Those have especially poor performances, so what would take 20sec on development environment on local could easily take 30 on heroku free plan, even on prod env. Anyway, if a request takes more than 10 secs on local, that's a problem. What local server logs tell you about time passed in views / activerecord ?

Comment: No, I have a paid plan. Does more than 10 sec requests on local mean that my code is poor? In this case, I'll think to reconsider my controller's index method. New relic also says Response#find is the huge part of requests. There are lots of records and I have to classify them somehow. By the way, local console says: "Completed 200 OK in 1157ms (Views: 113.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1041.1ms)" Is this good enough?

Comment: 1sec in active record is big, but that's ok if you have a load of data (and it's certainly way under the 30sec limit). The fact that slow time is in `#find` is interesting, since you don't use it in code you shown. Is there any before_filter, after_filter, or any other method that calls `#find` ?

Comment: about 10 sec in dev env : it not necessary means your code is poor (it may be, but can't say just like that). You may handle especially hard tasks which cannot be reduced in time. In that case, most of the time, we use a background job to precompute data, then use precomputed data in web interface. In no case simply querying database should takes so long, though (that's the whole point of databases).

Comment: There are two before_filters but they are pretty basic. I'll make some research how to write background job then. Thanks a lot for your concern.